# Using data from row 2 to calculate on row 1 in a view

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, sum

I've created a view to calculate income and expenses and next I'd want to calculate from these figures a profit and a ratio.  I could arguably export the view as it is and look to run the calculations I want in Crystal reports, but I wondered if there is a way to get the results in SQL first.  The simple view looks like this:

```
GroupID|GroupName|Expenses|Income
1      |Sales    |NULL    |100,000
2      |Expenses |75,000  |NULL
```

I'd like to sum Income from group 1 less Expenses from group 2 and have that displayed either as a new row or column.

Edit------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Would be looking for result sets in the potentially like this:

```
GroupID|GroupName|Expenses|Income  |Profit 
1 |     Sales    |NULL    |100,000 |25,000 
2 |Expenses      |75,000  |NULL    |NULL
```

OR

```
GroupID|GroupName|Expenses|Income 
1      |Sales    |NULL    |100,000 
2      |Expenses |75,000  |NULL 
3      |PROFIT   |25,000  |NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it be easier to just add the column at the end with a sign and then perform a sum on it in crystal reports.

```
 GroupID |GroupName     |Expenses|Income  |Profit 
 1       |Sales         |NULL    |100,000 |100,000 
 2       |Expenses      |75,000  |NULL    |-75,000
```

The net result would be a profit of 25,000.